# Closure argument becomes nil

Tags: ios, swift2

I have a weird issue trying to validate user input. I'm using a wrapper for a form framework and I want it to be able to validate user input.
The trouble is, when I call the closure with the userValue argument, it ends up being nil and all checks return false:

```
class FormRowWrap {
    var tag: String
    var row: AnyObject
    var verification: (value: Any?) -> Bool
    init(tag: String, row:AnyObject, verification:(Any?) -> Bool) {
        self.tag = tag
        self.row = row
        self.verification = verification
    }
}

class InsertViewController: FormViewController {

let rows = [
    {
        let tag = "Fuel Name"
        let row = FormRowWrap(tag: tag,
            row:TextRow(tag) {
                $0.title = tag
                //                $0.value = last known user default
            },
            verification:({(value: Any?) -> Bool in
                if let thing = value as? String { 
//^----- the value in a **breakpoint here is nil**
//
                    if !thing.isEmpty {
                        return true
                    }
                }
                return false
            }))
        return row
        }() as FormRowWrap,

    {
        let tag = "Price"
        let row = FormRowWrap(tag: tag,
```

...

```
func formValuesAreValid(values: [String: Any?]) -> Bool {
    var result = false
    for rowWrap in self.rows {
        let userValue = values[rowWrap.tag]
        print("userValue      \(userValue) forTag: \(values[rowWrap.tag])")
// ^---- this prints userValue      **Optional(Optional("Ghh")) forTag: Optional(Optional("Ghh"))**
        let entryIsValid = rowWrap.verification(value: userValue)

        if (!entryIsValid) {
            result = false
            return result
        }
    }
    result = true
    return result
}
```

If I run rowWrap.verification(value:"test") it returns true, so I think it's an issue about properly unwrapping values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function needs an Optional but `userValue` is an Optional inside another Optional:

> Optional(Optional("Ghh"))

So when you force unwrap it with

```
let entryIsValid = rowWrap.verification(value: userValue!)
```

what happens actually is that you unwrap the *first layer* and get back an Optional:

> Optional("Ghh")

which is what your function signature

```
(value: Any?) -> Bool
```

needs.

About *why* it's wrapped twice:

with

> formValuesAreValid(values: [String: Any?])

the values in the `values` dictionary are Optionals, and then when you access the dictionary:

```
let userValue = values[rowWrap.tag]
```

you get yet another Optional - because accessing a dictionary always returns an Optional, so in this case `values[rowWrap.tag]` returns an "Optional Optional".

Then somewhere else you unwrap once thinking you'll get the value `if let thing = value as? String` but you get the inner Optional instead and your next check fails.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to make it work by force unwrapping the "userValue":

let entryIsValid = rowWrap.verification(value: userValue!)

I still don't understand why this works and why it doesn't work with the argument as wrapped optional.